# ajax success function not called in ie7

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm sorry to post a question that's already been posted many times. But I can't find the answer to my specific problem. I have a form that's being submitted through the jQuery ajax() method. It works perfectly in Firefox and Safari. But in Internet Explorer 7 the success function is not being executed.

My javascript code looks like this:

```
/* FORM SCRIPT */
$('#creactform').submit( submitForm ); 

$('a.vrzknoplink').click(function(){
    alert('stap 1');
    var contactForm = $('#creactform');
    // Submit the form to the PHP script via Ajax
    $('ul#vrzknop').fadeOut(function() {
        $('p#wachttext').fadeIn();
    });

    // Actually send the form info to PHP script
    $.ajax( {
      url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
      type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
      dataType: 'json',
      data: contactForm.serialize(),
      success: submitFinished   
    } );

    // Handle the Ajax response     
    function submitFinished( response ) {
        alert(response.Result);

        if ( response.Result == "OK" ) {
            $('div#formdiv').fadeOut("fast",function() {
                $('div#successmessage').show();
                $('p#wachttext').fadeOut();
            });
            $('.formfields').val( "" );
            $('.inputtextarea').val( "" );
            $('div#successmessage').delay(6000).fadeOut("fast",function() {
                $('div#formdiv').show();
                $('ul#vrzknop').show();
            });                 
        } 
        else if (response.Result == "ERROR" && response.ErrorCode == "missing_fields") {
            alert("De velden met een * zijn verplicht om de aanvraag te versturen.");
            $('ul#vrzknop').show();
        }
    };
    return false;
});


function submitForm() {
  return false;
};
```

I've found posts with this question where the problem was a trailing comma,
I've found posts where the solution was setting cache to false

That didn't work for me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting cache to false?   `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});`

Comment: Yes, i've tried that. Didn't work. Did I put it in the right place of the script? I've put it right in front of the $.ajax function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray!! It works! I've changed the datatype from 'json' to 'jsonp'. That did the trick.

A little background information for anyone who might have the same issue. I'm using the Formmail PHP script from tectite to process the form and send it to my mailbox. To be honest I'm not really shure why it works now, I'm just a beginner in web programming.

Thanks wirey, for your reply to this post!